# Reset layer product collection filter in search

Tags: blocks, layered-navigation, catalogsearch, search

I am writing a block which subclasses `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Category` to display a list of products in each category.  To do this I apply `addCategoryFilter()` to the layer product collection for each layer filter item, first using `clear()` to remove any other filters.  So I end up with `$this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->clear()->addCategoryFilter($category)` for each item.

The problem is the last-displayed category filter is not being cleared before the rest of the page renders.  So the sidebar layered navigation is still filtered by it.  How can I clear it?? I have tried doing `$this->getLayer()->getProductCollection->clear()` in `_afterToHtml()` but with no luck. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is getLayer is a singleton and holds afaik one collection. There is no easy way to achieve what you want. You can unset the whole collection (maybe) after doing whatever you are doing (which I didnt understand)

Answer (score -1):

Try this before you taking the collection from layer

```
Mage::unregister('_singleton/catalog/layer');
```